# Probability of factor of particular size

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, factorization

What is the probability that an integer $a$ picked uniformly in $[t/2,t]$ has a factor in $[t^{\alpha},2t^{\alpha}]$ where $\alpha\in(0,1)$? I am interested when $\alpha=1/3$ but if there is a general result it would be useful. Is there a good asymptotic in terms of $t$ and $\alpha$ and is it $1/\mathrm{polylog}(t^\alpha)$?